# (Join tables normalized schema) SQL Statement to Select WHERE [x] AND WHERE [Y]

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, amazon-redshift

I have a normalized sql db consisting of two tables, let's call them `Users` and `Cars`, each User has many cars and each car belongs to a user, now I want to get all the users that owe two (or more) particular models of cars, pseudo: `select all users (join cars) that owe car model X and car model Y`,

This works to get all users that have either one of each models cars:

```
("""SELECT * FROM users use 
    JOIN cars car ON use.user_id = car.user_id 
    WHERE (car.model = 'X' AND car.maker = 'XX') 
    OR (car.model = 'Y' AND car.maker = 'YY');""")
```

But I want to get only the users that own both cars, I tried with `AND` instead of `OR` but that doesn't return any results

Comment: My bad, fixed. Postgres but planning to move it to redshift

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user id by doing:

```
SELECT c.user_id
FROM cars c
WHERE (c.model, c.maker) in ( ('X', 'XX'), ('Y', 'YY') )
GROUP BY c.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.model) = 2;
```

You can use `join`, `in`, or `exists` to bring in more information about the users.

This syntax uses a short-hand for your logic, using `in`. Of course, the explicit `and`/`or` logic is fine as well.

SQLFiddle on the above http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/669f6c/1

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  u.* 
from 
  users u 
where 
  exists (select 1 from cars c where c.maker = "Ford" and c.model='Mustang' and u.id = 
    c.user_id)
  and exists (select 1 from cars c where c.maker = "Chevy" and c.model='Camaro' and u.id = 
    c.user_id)
```